# How to design a LSTM network , which accept multiple input

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Here is the scenario, I want to create a contextual chatbot, which means the bot will answer or reply based on context. As an example

```
Input :["text": "it was really nice", "topic":movie]
Output:["text": "indeed,it was an awesome movie","topic":movie]
```

Whenever I have to consider the only one thing about the input, which is the sentence itself I can do it, all I need to do is to tokenize the sentences and feed into the input of LSTM. But how can I consider "topic"?

I have already prepared a dataset, in such a format.

I am using Keras to build such a bot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want to build.
The first thing that comes to mind is a normal generativ lstm like this one
https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/lstm_text_generation.html

wich generates text based on nietches works.
To use such a network you would need your training data in a question?, answer format.
And you would need to set your question as the seed.
You do not need to load the topic seperatly, as the concept of a neural net is that it learns on its own to understand the data.